# Font of calendar in Preference pane of macOS

Tags: macos, font, system-settings

What font is used in the calendar of macOS Date & Time preference pane?  Like the left box of this image, where it says `Nov 2018` and `Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa` and `28 29 30 31 1 2 3 ...`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use font identifiers for this, in case they have this in their database.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/visual-design/typography/

This suggests SF pro for macOS in recent versions.

> Since its introduction, San Francisco has gradually replaced most of
>   Apple's other typefaces on their software and hardware products and
>   for overall branding[13] and has replaced Helvetica Neue and Lucida
>   Grande as the system typeface of macOS and iOS since OS X El Capitan
>   and iOS 9.[14][3][15] Apple uses it on its website and for its product
>   wordmarks, where it replaced Myriad Pro. It is also used on the
>   keyboard of the 2015 MacBook and on the 2016 MacBook Pro, replacing
>   VAG Rounded.[16] It is also used as Apple's corporate typeface.[17]
>
> Apple restricts the usage of the typeface by others. It is licensed to
>   registered third-party developers only for the design and development
>   of applications for Apple's platforms.[3]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(sans-serif_typeface)#Usage